# How to click a link inside a webtable using WebDriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The following code is the HTML for

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="192">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rhs-customer" valign="top">
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img hspace="6" align="left" alt="" src="../common/images/icon-contactus.gif">
          <a onclick="window.open('../applications/homeline.asp','HomeLineNumber','height=500, width=700,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1,top=0,left=0')" href="#">&nbsp;**Call Us**</a>
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to click on the link "**Call us**", if you could please help, i'm new to WebDriver.

I am using the below xpath to attempt clicking the link, but i get thrown `NoSuchElementException`.

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/p[2]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Please post the full html code. Most probably you have the wrong path to the element. Maybe you should try: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/p[2]/a")).click();`

Comment: In your partial html code above, it is difficult to figure out the tree structure to help you. Try pasting it into a good text editor such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and using the Tidy plugin to automatically indent it for you. It'll make it much clearer to look at.

Comment: @vincebowdren i did the clearing of the question and html for him, but yeah i'd also have to note there was a lot of unnecessary code, as well there still is, didn't modify the tree though, you could see clearly there is a lot of unused tags on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Call Us")).click();
```

Comment: +1. It's usually better to find a simple and precise xpath using whatever local attributes are available, rather than a long absolute xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different XPath expression:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()="${nbsp}**Call Us**"]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your page in Firefox, then using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and the [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) add-on to debug your xpath. It's much quicker than posting your xpath and part of your html here, and letting somebody else make guesses at what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Providing this is the only place in your WebPage you have `class="rhs-customer"`, you can always isolate and search withing given elements. If this scenario is true, the below code should work like a charm:

```java
WebElement myTd = driver.findElement(By.className("rhs-customer"));
WebElement callUs = myTd.findElement(By.tagName("a"));

callUs.click();
```

As a side note, it's always advisable having some unique locators on your HTML, if given possible.